# Making subwoofer for car, without amplifier

Tags: amplifier, automotive, speakers, low-pass, diy

So, I have these two things and I want to achive a good subwoofer for my car: an 5.1 home theater system with a 20-30w 4ohm subwoofer and a radio player in my car with 4x45w 4ohm output for speakers.

As far, I cleaned everything from the subwoofer(the amplifier for the 5.1) and now its just the speaker part with the 2pin cable. A tied with one of the chanels from the radio player, and its working, but.. The subwoofer gots the main signal and isn't sounds like before.

I mean its okay, but I want to cut off the high frequencies, because I hear like he wants to be a normal speaker. Any low cost ideas? I was thinking about a low-pass filter, but as far as I know I can't make it this way. Tell my if I'm wrong.

(It may sounds dumb what I ask, but I want a DIY, cheap method. This area its totally new for me.)

Comment: A series inductor (coil of wire) of sufficient inductance will cut the high frequencies.

Comment: I think you'll find that's a good thump in a car you need more than 40 Watts...

Comment: Welcome. Google Amazon or Pyramid Audio for "subwoofer filters". Just buy something already made on a small board. The cost is ok unless you need something to handle hundreds of watts. We can give you equations, but winding air inductors with medium/heavy gauge wire is tedious...

Comment: ^^^   ALOT more than 40W.    And forget about a "passive" filter (i.e. coil of wire)... A simple 1st order filter like that isn't going to have a sharp enough cutoff to do what you want.    DO as above suggests, buy a pre-fab one.  They're available on Amazon for like $10

Comment: Did you use the .1 channel?

Comment: At first, thank you for your answers! You guys would be suprised what this little sub can do. :D I know, that everyone comes with 500w subs etc., but I want just a lil bit bass. :) Any product names would be appreciated, or a little detail, what parameters should I look for? @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 what do you mean with the .1 channel?

Comment: 5.1 is 5 full audio ch + 1 bass output

Comment: Ohh, there is no channel. I mean, the radio has 4 chanels(RR, RL, FR, FL) and from one of these is a 2pin cable directly to the sub's magnet. This home theather system is 10+ years old, and had a built-in amplifier(in the subwoofer case), with direct wires to the subwoofer and 5 outputs chanels. So this is what I cleaned up, and now its the subwoofer with nothing else in it. It would be better if I could make it work like the normal state, but I cant make a 220V in a car.